# Nike Account Creation / Creator

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have been having issues & are a complete noob, have read quite something as well as watched videos, but I seem to not be able to get past this one.

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://nike.com/de")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("hf_title_signin_membership")
element.click()
```

If anyone could help me, that'd be greatly appreciated, you can also DM Boni#6011 on discord :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: "Having issues" isn't very clear... what are you having issues with? Are you getting an error message? Edit your question and add any error messages and indicate which line it's coming on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only just updated you path or have not done so yet first make sure chrome driver is added to your path and then make sure to reboot your device to make sure the changes can take affect. Although it may look like the changes have been made when you type path in command prompt chromed river does not function correctly until the device is rebooted.

If you need to add it to your path -

[https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20terminal%20and,Type%20Y%20to%20save](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20terminal%20and,Type%20Y%20to%20save)

Comment: Hey, yea I have found a way arowund it, do you know how to work with csv & text files? Like that the bot uses Proxies out of the txt file & information such as email & password out of the csv file& then once created is supposed to put the mail:pass into another txt file

Comment: Im sorry if im reading this incorrectly but do you just need to know how to open a text file and write to it in which case you can run `text = open("<YOUR FILE NAME>", "r"` to read it the "r" on the end is used to tell it to read the file this can be changed for "w", to clear the file, "a" to append or write to the file and a few others but those are you main ones so from there you have the file open in your program set into a mode so you can tell your program `text.writelines(<String Pulled By Selenium>)` so the next time you open that .txt file it will have that written within, hope it helps